# Helpers vs. C# Classes? When to use what

Tags: c#, javascript, razor, asp.net-webpages

Hi Ladies and Gentlemen,

I am new to Razor coming from Java. I'm slightly confused on on the role of helpers. How are they different than defining a C# class that does the same thing? When would you use a helper over creating a class and calling methods of that class?

Perhaps, for reference one could use [this example](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/learning-the-basics-of-using-the-twitter-api-in-aspnet-web-pages-with-razor-syntax).

Perhaps for completion, How would Helpers and client-side Javascript fit together when programming a web application? It seems like they would overlap alot?

Best,

Georges

Comment: Eeh? The `MyCustomHelpers` in your example **IS** a static C# class with the method `TwitterSearch(string value)`... The difference in using this helper vs client-side JS is that the helper does the processing server-side, while the *client-side* JS does it... client-side :)

Answer (score 1):

So there at least two ways you can define helpers. Here is one way.

```
namespace MvcHelpers.Helpers
{
    public class ButtonHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString SpecialButton(string id)
        {
          return new MvcHtmlString(String.Format("<input id=\"{0}\" type=\"button\" value=\"Special\"/>", id));
        }
    }
}
```

I think that this is what you are referring to when you say "C# Classes" but in the reality they are just helpers also that make it easier to output HTML that will be rendered in you View.

Here is another method for designing helpers which is probably what you are referring to as a "helper".

```
namespace MvcHelpers.Helpers
{
    public static class ButtonHelperExtension
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString SpecialButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)
        {
          return new MvcHtmlString(String.Format("<input id=\"{0}\" type=\"button\" value=\"Special\"/>", id));
        }
    }
}
```

This is referred to as a helper extension and now we can reference this like all of the other standard HTML helpers. Here is how we reference these two type of helpers in the Razor view.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
@using MvcHelpers.Helpers;

<h2>Home Page</h2>

@ButtonHelper.SpecialButton("button1")
<br />
@Html.SpecialButton("button2")
```

Both techniques achieve exactly the same results.  The one referenced as Html.SpecialButton is the extension method. The only advantage I see to this is that it is clear that it is an HTML helper and not performing some other function.  People that are familiar with using HTML helpers will now see your new function when they use InteliSense.  But they do still have to put in the proper uses clause for it to show up.  So same results with slightly different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

helpers are suppose to help you create html controls like textbox, buttons, links among others that will enable you to build a responsive web application.  And in mvc you have two major types of helpers : Html helpers and Ajax Helpers. To use helpers with javascript, you should use Ajax Helpers. Anyway you should visit this links and read up on mvc helpers and on how to create custom helpers.

[Creating MVC Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

[Learning MVC helpers](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp)

Comment: Still not sure I understand the the high level concept...